# jQuery UI performance issues with a table in IE

Tags: jquery, performance, internet-explorer, jquery-ui, dhtml

I'm having problems getting UI code to perform at all well in IE.

I have a table - a matrix of values. Each cell can be empty or hold a list of items.

I want users to be able to drag items between cells.

So my HTML looks something like this:

```
<table>
    <tr><td></td><th scope="col">col 1</th><th scope="col">col 2</th></tr>
    <tr><th scope="row">row 1</th>
        <td class="droppable-cell">
            <div class="draggable-item">item A</div>
            <div class="draggable-item">item B</div>
        </td>
        <td class="droppable-cell"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><th scope="row">row 2</th>
        <td class="droppable-cell"></td>
        <td class="droppable-cell">
            <div class="draggable-item">item C</div>
            <div class="draggable-item">item D</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Then I'm using jQuery 1.3.1 and jQuery UI 1.6rc6:

```
$j('.draggable-item').each(function()
{
    $j(this).draggable({
       addClasses: false,
       revert: true, 
       zIndex: 2000,
       cursor: 'move'
    });
});

$j('.droppable-cell').each(function()
{
    $j(this).droppable({
        addClasses: false,
        activeClass: 'droppable-cell-candrop',
        hoverClass: 'droppable-cell-hover',
        tolerance: 'pointer',

        drop: function(event, ui)
        {
            //function to save change
        });
    });
});
```

Note that this is simplified, truncated and unfinished code.

My problem is that in FX, Safari, Chrome, etc (i.e. all the decent browsers) this works fine.

IE really struggles though.  With a 5x5 table IE's delay on the start of a drag is noticeable.  On a 10x10 table with maybe 100 items the start of the drag hangs the browser.

I want to be able to support up to round 20x15 cells and maybe up to 500 items - is this just impossible? It doesn't seem like it should be.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a way to do this that doesn't slow the page in IE like this?

Comment: i am also having this exact problem. large table, nested divs within table. firefox renders teh page within 10 seconds, ie renders the table after a wait of 2 minutes. firefox still zips along with teh drag and dtop, ie crawls.. infact it freezes, and the drag and drop sdoes not work.

am going to try some of teh solutions below. the fixed width, and the #id tagname.class references. But i do fear that it will still be slow. if anyone else has some good i deas, I would be all ears.

Comment: Yeah - my solution to this was to limit IE users - they can only select a tiny subset of the rows and columns that FX and Chrome users can. Even then IE8 only just copes with maybe 25 cells (5x5 grid), 7 and 6 remain hopeless. It brings back memories of late 90s web development and is an ugly thing to do, but what else can you do if their browser is so poor?

Comment: Having same issue, IE is super slow with large grid, but Chrome and Firefox are fine.

Answer (score 3):

Narrowing the portion of the DOM that jQuery has to search may help. Add an id to the containing DOM element

```
<table id="myTable">
```

Then alter your jQuery selector to find elements within this container

```
$j('#myTable .draggable-item').each(function() { ...
```

Comment: I thought this was $('#myTable,.draggable-item') according to the documentation.

Comment: @Jay. Nope, I was refering to 'Ancestor Descendent' selectors (http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/descendant#ancestordescendant). A comma would be an 'n' selector (http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/multiple#selector1selector2selectorN) which is useful in some cases but not this one

Comment: That helps a little, though it's still crushingly slow in IE

Comment: disapointing improovement. the main problem seems to be ie's very very very slow rendering. I watched it flog one of the cpu's at 100% to render a table with 56 columns, and 34 rows for 7 and a half minutes. dragging and dropping took a good 30 seconds to start and stop. there are only 80 odd divisons to drag around amongst all those cells.

Answer (score 2):

This exact issue is why iGoogle and other simliar apps use a transparent box with a dotted line around the edge.  IE is unable to drag full objects, because of the issue you have outlined above.

Comment: Do you mean http://www.google.com/ig ? Even in IE that page drags the actual content. I'm only trying to drag small divs.

Answer (score 2):

It could be the table rendering... Can you try without the table?

If your cells are the same size you can achieve the table-like display floating them:

```
<style>
.droppable-cell{
  float:left; width: 50%; height: 20px; border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>

<div class="droppable-cell">
        <div class="draggable-item">item A</div>
        <div class="draggable-item">item B</div>
</div>
<div class="droppable-cell"></div>
<div class="droppable-cell"></div>
<div class="droppable-cell">
        <div class="draggable-item">item C</div>
        <div class="draggable-item">item D</div>
</div>
```

If using a table is a must setting the [table-layout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531161.aspx) style to 'fixed' and specifying the cells size may help.

Comment: Thanks, nice idea - but this is really tabular data. The row and column headers are hierarchical with spans. I also don't think I could fix the cell size.

Answer (score 1):

my work around is dropping the 'activeClass' from the droppable definition, and only using 'hoverClass'.

On a table of about 150 rows with about 10 columns. It went from 10 secs of lag to less than 1.  The dragging becomes a little jerky, but not unusable.