# Need a Javascript Incompatibility Example

Tags: javascript

I am currently looking around for a javascript example that can demonstrate the incompatibility or behavior issues in different browsers.

I have tried everything suggested here: Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/565641/what-cross-browser-issues-have-you-faced) without luck.

Can anyone give me an example on this please. It is for teaching purposes.

Thanks in advance

P/S: The example should be applicable for all of the current modern browser (the latest version)

Comment: what are the target browsers?

Comment: @user2181397 - `all of the current modern browser (the latest version)` - which is good, because there's no need to worry about internet explorer at all as it is no way a modern browser - that reduces the incompatibility issues by 90%

Answer (score 1):

Try going to http://caniuse.com/. Different browsers will implement the latest features at different speeds and hence you can showcase the incompatibilities this way.

e.g.

```
(()=>console.log('hello'))();
```

works in chrome but not in IE11

Comment: Does IE11 support *any* ES6 features?

Comment: const and let are supported

Answer (score 0):

```
var text = new Text('Oh, how quick that fox was!');
```

Works in chrome, but not IE.

There's a large list of incompatibilities at http://quirksmode.org/compatibility.html

Test page for the above constructor at http://quirksmode.org/dom/core/createElements.html

Comment: IE is not a modern browsesr